# Silverlight closing UserControl Childwindow

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, childwindow

On my project I show a Usercontrol childwindow for logging in. Now when I want to submit the login values (username, password) the content of that childwindow has become null... You prob think that I made it a 2nd time but no...

Here is my code for creating the childwindow. And for closing it (that's where it fails)

```
public void openLoginWindow()
        {            
            if (login == false)
            {
                window.Content = new LoginView();
                window.HasCloseButton = false;

                window.Show();
            }
            else
            {

                window.Close();
            }

        }
```

Thank's for the help

Evert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is that LoginView object?  Is it a custom usercontrol?  I'm not sure how your system is working but what I would do is create a specific childwindow for logging in (in that childwindow you can use your LoginView object if you want).  Then in code :

```
public void openLoginWindow()
{
   LoginChildWindow dlg = new LoginChildWindow();
   dlg.HasCloseButton = false;
   dlg.Closed += new EventHandler(dlg_Closed);

   dlg.Show();
}

void dlg_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            LoginChildWindow dlg = ((LoginChildWindow)sender);
            dlg.Closed -= dlg_Closed;

            //Retrieve your values here
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. I was making a 'circle' but thx for the answer.